# How to solve this Cauchy's problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

How to solve this  Cauchy's problem?

$\frac{dx_1}{dt}= \frac{x_1Q(t)}{2 \pi (x_1^2+x_2^2)}, $

$\frac{dx_2}{dt}= \frac{x_2Q(t)}{2 \pi (x_1^2+x_2^2)},$

$x_i(0)=\xi_i$

There $Q(t)>0$ is some "good" function

Comment: Hello @boris2018aa, welcome to MSE. Please add your attempts in the question and explain where exactly you got stuck. This will make it easier for others to help you and give a bespoke answer.

Comment: @Ernie060, my question is answered. Should I upload the photos of my attempts (I don't know all rules of forum)?

Comment: No. It is best you do not upload photos. The best thing to do is to type your attemps in your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). And about my comment: since you are a new user, I just wanted to inform you that it is best to add your attempts in your question. Sometimes, questions without any effort are not received very well on MSE.

Comment: @Ernie060, I understand you. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r:=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ so$$r\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac12\frac{d}{dt}(x_1^2+x_2^2)=x_1\frac{dx_1}{dt}+x_2\frac{dx_2}{dt}=\frac{Q(t)}{2\pi},$$i.e. $x_1^2+x_2^2-\xi_1^2-\xi_2^2=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^tQ\left(t^\prime\right)dt^\prime$. Note also that $\frac{d}{dt}\ln\frac{x_1}{x_2}=0$, so $x_1\propto x_2$.

Comment: I'm trying to do this. But in the book the answer is $x_i=\frac{r\xi_i}{r_0}$, where $r_0 = \sqrt(\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2), r= (r_0^2+\frac{1}{\pi}\int^t_0 Q(m)dm)^{0.5}$. OH! I have a mistake in the task

Comment: I'm sorry, now task is right

Comment: I'm trying to use polar coordinates, but I can't obtain the result

Comment: @boris2018aa I've changed it.

Comment: What does $\propto$ mean? "Is proportional to..."? If it so, I understand your solution. Thanks!

Comment: @boris2018aa That's right, yes.